# Как добавить ключ значение во вложенный объект формдаты?

Tags: javascript, ajax, formdata

У меня есть объект такого типа:

```
sendObect: {
  name: 'value',
  age: 'value',
  family: {
   father: 'value',
   mother: 'value'
  }
}
```

и я хочу отправить это с помощью new Formdata()

```
let fd = new FormData()
let family = sendObect.family
Object.keys(sendObect).forEach(el => {
  if(el != 'family') {
    fd.append(el, sendObect[el])
  } else {
   fd.append('family', JSON.stringify(family))
  }
})
```

И затем мне нужно добавить в объект family еще одно ключ-значение
Подскажите, как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так?

```js
let sendObect= {
  name: 'value1',
  age: 'value2',
  family: {
   father: 'value3',
   mother: 'value4'
  }
}

let fd = new FormData()
Object.keys(sendObect).forEach(el => {
  if(el !== 'family') {
    fd.append(el, sendObect[el])
  } else {
    fd.append('family', JSON.stringify(sendObect[el]))
  }
})
let family = JSON.parse(fd.get('family'));
family.brother = "value5";
fd.set('family', JSON.stringify(family))

console.log('name =', fd.get('name'));
console.log('age =', fd.get('age'));
console.log('family =', fd.get('family'));
```

Comment: Да, спасибо.
Если можно еще один вопрос, а если я хочу добавить картинку вместо обычной строки в .brother ?
Я обычно ее добавляю так - fd.append('photo', blob, 'brother.png'), а как в этом случае это можно сделать?

Comment: @Alexandr боюсь во вложенный не выйдет, может только если  в base64 перегнать, или аттачить к формдате с рандомным уникальным ключом , а во вложенный объект типа ссылку на него

Comment: Я понял, спасибо Вам.

Comment: @Alexandr обращайтесь